# how to split data on page.load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, alphabetical

i have an alphabetical menu.
and problem is that data is showed in one long list at the beginning, and just after clicking on some Letter it will be showed under groups.

FALSE at the pageload.

i need to have it already splitted in groups like this (happens after click on A or B)

and here is my **function**

```
$(function () {

            debugger;
            var _alphabets = $('.alphabet > a');
            var _contentRows = $('#countries-table tbody tr');

            _alphabets.click(function () {
                var _letter = $(this), _text = $(this).text(), _count = 0;

                _alphabets.removeClass("active");
                _letter.addClass("active");

                _contentRows.hide();
                _contentRows.each(function (i) {
                    var _cellText = $(this).children('td').eq(0).text();
                    if (RegExp('^' + _text).test(_cellText)) {
                        _count += 1;
                        $(this).fadeIn(400);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: I think you just need to manually trigger .click() event: `_alphabets.first().trigger("click");`

Comment: post it as an answer, i will rate it, perfect solution!

Comment: Already did, just wasn't sure enough and answer starting with "I think" isn't that good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to manually trigger `.click()` event, you can do that on the first element:

```
_alphabets.click(function () {
    //...
});

//trigger manually:
_alphabets.first().trigger("click");
```